# how i Get usb number port from connected device via python

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian

I want know which device connect to which usb port in ubuntu ...
for example when I connect bluetooth dongle to usb I want know to which usb port Bluetooth is connected.

When I run:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

in can see usb port number like this:

```
Jul 27 20:51:58 Smart-Installer kernel: [  711.363300] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
Jul 27 20:51:58 Smart-Installer kernel: [  711.363331] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

I want get `usb 1-1.2` programmatically via python

I know `lsusb -t` get me port but I want also device number and `-t` get me a few data

Answer (score 0):

You can either use PyUSB (python-usb package in Ubuntu and Debian), or walk through /sys/bus/usb/devices yourself, all the info is there in plain text.

Comment: thanks i write python script to monitor /var/log/messages log file and get info from this file